# Strongloop: slc command not found

Tags: strongloop

After running sudo npm install -g strongloop,  the slc command is not found as it should be.

I am running node v0.12.6, npm v3.3.9 on OSX.

Here is the path that npm spits out... incase that helps:

```
/Users/peter/.node/bin/slc -> /Users/peter/.node/lib/node_modules/strongloop/bin/slc.js
/Users/peter/.node/bin/lb-ng -> /Users/peter/.node/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-sdk-angular-cli/bin/lb-ng
/Users/peter/.node/lib
```

Here is some info about my node config:

```
which node: /usr/local/bin/node
which npm: /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo npm config get globalconfig= /Users/peter/.node/etc/npmrc
sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH' = /Users/peter/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with my node install.

I fixed it by completely uninstalling node and then reinstalling.

I used the following commands:

```
brew uninstall node;
brew prune;
rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm;
rm -f /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d;
rm -rf ~/.npm;
```

and then to re-install:

```
brew install node;
which node #=> /usr/local/bin/node
export NODE_PATH='/usr/local/lib/node_modules' # add to bashrc if not already there
```

I found these commands here--> [how to uninstall and reinstall node on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)